# Failing to populate selectInput choices with column names of user uploaded .csv

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I've tried this probably 10 different ways and the best I can do is get "name" "id" and "class" to show up in my selectinput columns once I upload a .csv.

How do I get my uploaded data's column names to populate the selectInput choices?

Here's the relevant UI and Server Code I'm working with. Forgive my ignorance, I'm just diving into Shiny for the first time.

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(fluidRow(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test"),
    h4("Test"),
    mainPanel(width=750,
              # File Upload
              fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File (WILL ONLY GIVE YOU A SUMMARY rn)",
                        multiple = TRUE,
                        accept = c("text/csv",
                                   "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                   ".csv"))),
           tabsetPanel(type="tab", 
                  tabPanel("Summary",
                        varSelectInput(inputId = "VarX", label="Select", data =  tableOutput("selectfile")
                                       ))
))`

# ------------------------------------------------------------------

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  rawData <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
  })
  
datacolumns<- eventReactive(input$file1{
 
    if(is.null(input$file1)) {return()}
    df<-read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    df

  
})

output$selectfile<-renderTable({
  datacolumns()
})
```

I am trying to get the user uploaded data's column names to populate the selectinput choices.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` argument of `varSelectInput` takes a data.frame as argument not a `tableOutput`. And as the dataset is uploaded by the user you could use `updateVarSelectInput` inside an `observe`r to update the `data` argument and hence the choices according to the uploaded dataset:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

#write.csv(mtcars, "mtcars.csv", row.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Test"),
  h4("Test"),
  mainPanel(
    width = 750,
    # File Upload
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File (WILL ONLY GIVE YOU A SUMMARY rn)",
      multiple = TRUE,
      accept = c(
        "text/csv",
        "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
        ".csv"
      )
    )
  ),
  tabsetPanel(
    type = "tab",
    tabPanel(
      "Summary",
      varSelectInput(inputId = "VarX", label = "Select", data = NULL)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rawData <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
  })

  observe({
    req(rawData())
    updateVarSelectInput(inputId = "VarX", data = rawData())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! That little hurdle is all I needed to start me on a roll :)

You're the best!